# Get google search data without using google in Android?

Tags: android

Hello All I want to search Images from the google search but I dont want to use google site/ browser. I want to make my own layout in that when user searched for any images then it will display the result which is displaed when we searched the same image in google.

Can any one tell me the intent for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Google Image Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/v1/jsondevguide.html) (FYI, its now deprecated).

For example, search images of me using this URL: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=paresh%20mayani'

You just have to make a call on this URL and get a JSON response. Once you have JSON response, then you have to parse it and display wherever you want, may you display it inside the GridView or GalleryView.

FYI, i have already did this in one of my application and its working fine even today (After its deprecation even).

**Result set on Browser:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer but I am not able to click this. It will directly ask for saveing this file.

Comment: check attached image and don't worry, it will return result sets in JSON whenever you make a web call by android code.

Comment: Ok so after passing this URL I have to make simple json parsing, is it? Can you post the parsing code, which is working in you application? Thanks.

Comment: You can have JSON Parsing example here: http://goo.gl/08HAz , go through this example first and try to implement the same for the above JSON response.

Comment: I want to search only images like in google, Images are there then the same URL is used?

Comment: get the "url" value given in JSON response. My dear go and try to implement first. Without don't throw any confusions here. I know you are smart enough but it should not be the case to implement corerctly.

Comment: @PareshMayani how to search image by uploading image on google ?? Is there any API for that ???

Answer (score 0):

You can try Google search API. http://google.com/complete/search?output=json&q=YOURSEARCHEDTERM or for XML output http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=YOURSEARCHEDTERM. Not sure how it can be used with images. May be with little changes you can get it work.